# How do SystemColors work?

Tags: wpf, resources

If I write

```
test = Application.Current.FindResource(SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrushKey);
```

test will have a value even though Application.Current.Resources is empty.

How does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FindResource` will first look in application-scope resources for the specified resource. Application-scope resources are managed by `Application`, and are exposed from the `Resources` property.

If the specified resource is not found in the set of application-scope resources, FindResource then next searches the system resources. System resources are shell resources defined by the user, and include colors, fonts, and shell configurations. These are exposed from the `SystemColors`, `SystemFonts`, and `SystemParameters` types, respectively, as static properties.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.findresource.aspx